# JLabel text complete

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, settext

I have a JLabel with a text bigger than the width size, so the text is showed like this:

[image]

what i want is that the text showed cutted like this:

[image: elll]

I can't change de sizeWidth of the label is necesary the size that i put it
this is the lines:

```
Cuadros[5].setText("Auto Incremet");
Cuadros[5].setSize(ImgA(Cuadros[5]), ImgL(Cuadros[5]));
```

Thanks for your advices,
i hope can understan my idea :D

Comment: Let the [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
 final JLabel label = ...
...
label.setText("prototype text to define size");
final Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
label.setMinimumSize(size);
label.setPreferredSize(size);
...
label.setText(...);
```

Comment: I believe OP indicated that he **does not** want to re-size the label. He seems to be looking for a custom way to handle text truncation.

Answer (score 0):

This post isn't closed, so I hope posting an answer is okay. Anyway, I believe a solution could be nesting your `JLabel` in its own `JPanel`, so long as its layout is not something that requires the label to fit into hard boundaries on all sides, as `BorderLayout` or `GridLayout` would.

This is the example in question:

[image]
[image]

Here is the SSCCE demonstrating the example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TruncationTest1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Truncation Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Default layout, AKA FlowLayout
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Try resizing the frame: This will not be truncated for some reason.");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("However, this JLabel, on the other hand, will become truncated.");
        f.setSize((int)label.getPreferredSize().getWidth() + 40,65);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel);
            panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel.add(label);
        f.add(label2);
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```